# WebStorm show errors for relative paths with SCSS files

Tags: reactjs, webstorm, tsconfig, css-modules

WebStorm can't find the relative path in SCSS files in a React app and show the errors below.

The import is working, but WebStorm can't recognize the relative path and show these errors.

Application was created with cra and `baseUrl: src` was included in the tsconfig file. So everything is working, but the errors remain and autocomplete for the paths are not working.

```
Cannot resolve directory 'styles'
Cannot resolve file 'variaveis'
Cannot resolve directory 'assets'
Cannot resolve directory 'cardapio'
Cannot resolve file 'header.png'
Element 'padding-horizontal' is resolved only by name without use of explicit imports
Element 'padding-horizontal' is resolved only by name without use of explicit imports
```

**Cardapio.module.scss**

```css
@import "styles/variaveis";

.menu {
  padding: 20px $padding-horizontal;
}

.header {
  background-image: url('/assets/cardapio/header.png');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 300px;
}
```

I expect WebStorm to recognize the relative path and make autocomplete work properly.

For now what I did was disable the inspection just to get rid of the messages.

Here's my tsconfig file and the errors.

**tsconfig.json**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

[image: File structure]

Is there some config to make in tsconfig, package.json or even in WebStorm?

Answer (score 0):

`baseurl` ffrom `tsconfig.json` is not respected when resolving paths in SASS; related ticket: [WEB-57018](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-57018/paths-relative-to-tsconfig.json-jsconfig.json-baseurl-dont-work-in-CSS), feel free to upvote it to get notified on any progress.

As a workaround, I'd suggest marking the `src` folder as *Resource root* (**Mark Directory As/Resource Root** in folder right-click menu).